# How can I display a 2D binary matrix as a black & white plot?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I have a 2D binary matrix that I want to display as a black and white plot. For example, let's say I have a 4-by-4 matrix as follows:

```
1 1 0 1
0 0 1 0
1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0
```

How can this be plotted as a black and white matrix? Some of my input binary matrices are of size 100-by-9, so I would ideally need a solution that generalizes to different sized matrices.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to make a crossword-type plot [as shown here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html#bua4ysn) (with grid lines and black and white squares) you can use the [`imagesc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) function, a [gray colormap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#input_argument_d0e131488), and modify the [axes properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html) like so:

```
mat = [1 1 0 1; 0 0 1 0; 1 1 0 1; 1 0 0 0];  % Your sample matrix
[r, c] = size(mat);                          % Get the matrix size
imagesc((1:c)+0.5, (1:r)+0.5, mat);          % Plot the image
colormap(gray);                              % Use a gray colormap
axis equal                                   % Make axes grid sizes equal
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:(c+1), 'YTick', 1:(r+1), ...  % Change some axes properties
         'XLim', [1 c+1], 'YLim', [1 r+1], ...
         'GridLineStyle', '-', 'XGrid', 'on', 'YGrid', 'on');
```

And here's the image you should get:

[image]

Comment: Is there a method to change the style of the scale? I want to locate the numbers in below the center of the boxes, rather than aligned with the grid lines. I also want to label them as a vector that I designate, like [1,1,2,3,5], rather than the consecutive [1,2,3,4,5].

Comment: @qdmj You should be able to easily change the tick locations (values) and labels as described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I got your question right, but you may try the image function, like this:

```
A = [ 1 1 0; 1 0 1; 1 1 1 ];
colormap([0 0 0; 1 1 1 ]);
image(A .* 255);
```

Comment: thank you very much. this was helpful but not what as exactly as i need, i need something like this (please find the URL):
http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/pcolor1.gif

Answer (score 1):

Try the `spy` function to start with perhaps.