# How to convert binary codes to black and white images

Tags: image-processing, binary, image-conversion

Is there any software(or online website) which can be used to convert binary codes to black and white images (eg: 0 as black and 1 as white). i googled it but i didnt find any softwares now i am thinking to make it myself; i have experience in c,vb and php. do some body have a script in any of this language (preferable vb and php) that helps to convert binary to black and white image. I want to make image like this [How can I display a 2D binary matrix as a black & white plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280705/how-to-convert-2d-binary-matrix-to-black-white-plot) (i dont have matlab or have experience in it)

Comment: Do you want to use OpenCV library? It is easy in there.

Comment: @Aliostad I am new to Open Cv lib but i will try.. can you tell me how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585535/convert-rgb-to-black-white-in-opencv