# Heatmap a chacrter matrix

Tags: r, heatmap

I am new in R and I was wondering if I can heatmap my table or matrix which contain TRUE and FALSE ie :
   Condition1 Conditions2 . . .
Id1 TRUE          FALSE
Id2 FALSE         TRUE
.
.
.
My excuse for this naive question and any proposition is welcome to make a heatmap or any tool  to visualize my table or matrix by color code and apply clustering or dendrogram  based on it.
Thank you in advance

Comment: I found a similar question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280705/how-to-convert-2d-binary-matrix-to-black-white-plot)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can easily convert TRUE/FALSE to 1,0 numeric

```
x<-data.frame(y=sample(c(1, 0),10, replace=TRUE), z=sample(c(1, 0),10, replace=TRUE))
heatmap(as.matrix(x))
```

if needed, to change TRUE/FALSE to 1/0 ,

```
x[x==TRUE]<-1
x[x==FALSE]<-0
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need to turn T to 1 or F to 0. It will do that automatically.

Comment: Hmm, I get following error `Error in heatmap(as.matrix(x)) : 'x' must be a numeric matrix` without converting, may be for `image` its ok, but not for `heatmap`

Comment: it will do 1's and 0's with `as.numeric(x)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the image() function:

```
> x=matrix(c(T,F,T,F,F,F,T,T,F,T,T,T,F,F,F,T),ncol=4)
> x
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> image(t(x),axes=F)
> axis(2,at=seq(0,1,(1/(nrow(x)-1))),labels=nrow(x):1)
> axis(3,at=seq(0,1,(1/(ncol(x)-1))),labels=1:ncol(x))
```

Give it a shot!

Comment: +1! Shouldn't it, though, be `image(t(x)[,ncol(x):1])`? These squares give me a headache!