# How to build a crossword-like plot for a boolean matrix

Tags: r

I have a boolean matrix:

```
mm <- structure(c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                  FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
                  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                  FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                  FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                  TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                  TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                  TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                  TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                  TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), .Dim = c(10L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
                                                                          c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n1.1", "n2.1", "n3.1", "n4.1", 
                                                                            "n5.1")))
```

For this matrix, I'd like to make a plot similar to this one:

[image: crossword-like plot]

(the picture was taken from a similar question for Matlab: [How can I display a 2D binary matrix as a black & white plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280705/how-to-convert-2d-binary-matrix-to-black-white-plot))

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I don't see an easy way how to do that in R. So far, my best attempt is based on barplot:

```
m1 <- matrix(TRUE,ncol=10,nrow=10)
barplot(m1,col=mm)
```

but it makes all rows have the same colors.

Any ideas are welcome

Comment: I would recommend a look at `plotrix::color2D.matplot`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316363/plot-and-fill-chessboard-like-area-and-the-similars-in-r

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using ggplot2's `geom_tile` and reshape2's `melt`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

melted <- melt(mm)
ggplot(melted, aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, fill = value)) + geom_tile() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "black"))
```

To make it a bit neater, you could remove the legend and the gray edges with some adjustments to the theme:

```
ggplot(melted, aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, fill = value)) + geom_tile() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "black")) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Final output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few more approaches to round out the graphics options.

1. base graphics with `rect`:

   ```
   plot.new()
   par(mar=rep(0, 4))
   plot.window(xlim=c(0, ncol(mm)), ylim=c(0, nrow(mm)), asp=1)
   o <- cbind(c(row(mm)), c(col(mm))) - 1
   rect(o[, 1], o[, 2], o[, 1] + 1, o[, 2] + 1, col=t(mm)[, ncol(mm):1])
   ```

   [image]
2. `lattice::levelplot` and `latticeExtra`:

   ```
   library(latticeExtra)
   levelplot(t(mm)[, ncol(mm):1], asp=1, scales='sliced', 
             col.regions=c('white', 'black'), margin=FALSE, colorkey=FALSE) + 
     layer(panel.grid(h=nrow(mm)-1, v=ncol(mm)-1, col=1))
   ```

   [image]
3. `rasterVis::levelplot`, `raster`, and `latticeExtra`:

   ```
   library(rasterVis)
   library(latticeExtra)
   levelplot(raster(mm), col.regions=c('white', 'black'), 
             margin=FALSE, colorkey=FALSE) + 
     layer(panel.grid(h=nrow(mm)-1, v=ncol(mm)-1, col=1))
   ```

   [image]
4. `sp::spplot`, `raster`, and `latticeExtra`:

   ```
   library(raster)
   library(latticeExtra)
   spplot(raster(mm), colorkey=FALSE, col.regions=c('white', 'black')) +
     layer(panel.grid(h=nrow(mm)-1, v=ncol(mm)-1, col=1))
   ```

   [image]
5. `raster`

   It can be a bit fiddly to set the graphics device's dimensions such that `raster` doesn't plot additional (partial) cells outside the intended x and y limits. When using this approach, if the goal is to export to e.g. png, I plot to `windows`/`x11`/`quartz` first and resize the window until the plotted area is as I'd intended, then query the device dimensions with `dev.size()` and use these values to determine the dimension ratio for plotting to `png`.

   ```
   plot(raster(mm), legend=FALSE, col=c('white', 'black'))
   abline(h=seq(0, 1, len=nrow(mm) + 1), 
          v=seq(0, 1, len=ncol(mm) + 1))
   ```

   [image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach that uses `qheat` a wrapper for **ggplot2** from the **qdap** package:

```
library(qdap)
qheat(t(data.frame(mm)), by.column=NULL, high="black", text.color =NA,
    grid="grey20") + guides(fill=FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach using `plot` from the `graphics` package:

```
plot(rep(1:10, each = 10), rep(-(1:10), 10), axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE,
     pch = ifelse(mm, 0, 15), cex = 6, asp = 1, xpd = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting use of `pch`, but note that `cex` will have to be adjusted according to the size of the plotting device.