# GGVIS plot for logical matrix

Tags: r, matrix, plot, ggplot2, ggvis

I'm trying to plot a logical matrix similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035831/how-to-build-a-crossword-like-plot-for-a-boolean-matrix), the difference is that I'm trying to do it using `ggvis` so that I can use the hover tool (the data has several thousand rows so I'd like to see row/column names when I hover over it). The following code worked for me with `ggplot2`.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

melted = melt(matrix)
ggplot(melted, aes(x = Var2, y = Var1)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
    scale_file_manual(values = c("black", "red")) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
    coord_fixed(ratio = 1/10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an example for `layer_rects` [here](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/layers.html), I just made some adjustments.
Using the example for the linked question:

## Load data

```
mm <- structure(c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                  FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
                  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                  FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                  FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                  TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                  TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                  TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                  TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                  TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), .Dim = c(10L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
                                                                          c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n1.1", "n2.1", "n3.1", "n4.1", 
                                                                            "n5.1")))
```

## Melt and change types

```
library(reshape2)
melted <- melt(mm)

melted$value <- as.numeric(melted$value)
melted$Var1 <- as.factor(melted$Var1)
```

## Plot

```
melted %>%
  ggvis(~Var2, ~Var1, fill = ~value) %>%
  layer_rects(width = band(), height = band()) %>%
  scale_nominal("x", padding = 0, points = FALSE) %>%
  scale_nominal("y", padding = 0, points = FALSE)
```

[image]